# What is 'core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Self' in rust?

Tags: rust

This used to work:

```
struct Foo<'a, T> {
  parent:&'a (Array<T> + 'a)
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> { //'
  pub fn new<T>(parent:&Array<T>) -> Foo<T> {
    return Foo {
      parent: parent
    };
  }
}

trait Array<T> {
  fn as_foo(&self) -> Foo<T> {
    return Foo::new(self);
  }
}

fn main() {
}
```

Now it errors:

> :15:21: 15:25 error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Self`
>   :15     return Foo::new(self);

I can kind of guess what's wrong; it's saying that my impl of Foo<'a, T> is for T, not Sized? T, but I'm not trying to store a Sized? element in it; I'm storing a *reference* to a Sized element in it. That should be a pointer, fixed size.

I don't see what's wrong with what I'm doing, or why it's wrong?

For example, I should (I think...) be able to store a &Array in my Foo, no problem. I can't see any reason this would force my Foo instance to be unsized.

playpen link: http://is.gd/eZSZYv

Comment: I too am scratching my head at this one -- it's totally hosed https://github.com/bjz/algebra

Comment: although have look at this issue on the rust-lang tracker: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20550

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's two things going on here: trait objects coercions (the error), and object safety (fixing it).

### The error

As suggested by the error message, the difficult part of the code is the `Foo::new(self)`, and this is because `pub fn new<T>(parent: &Array<T>) -> ...`, that is, `self` is being coerced to an `&Array<T>` trait object. I'll simplify the code to:

```
trait Array {
  fn as_foo(&self) {
    let _ = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
  }
}

fn main() {}
```

which gives the same thing:

```
<anon>:3:13: 3:27 error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Self`
<anon>:3     let _ = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`Self` is the stand-in name for the type that implements the trait. Unlike most generic parameters, `Self` is possibly-unsized (`?Sized`) by default, since [RFC 546](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0546-Self-not-sized-by-default.md) and [#20341](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/20341) for the purposes of allowing e.g. `impl Array<T> for Array<T>` to work by default more often (we'll come to this later).

The variable `self` has type `&Self`. If `Self` is a sized type, then this is a normal reference: a single pointer. If `Self` is an unsized type (like `[T]` or a trait), then `&Self` (`&[T]` or `&Trait`) is a slice/trait object: a fat pointer.

The error appears because the only references `&T` that can be cast to a trait object are when `T` is sized: Rust doesn't support making fat pointers fatter, only thin pointer → fat pointer is valid. Hence, since the compiler doesn't *know* that `Self` will always be `Sized` (remember, it's special and `?Sized` by default) it has to assume the worst: that the coercion is not legal, and so it's disallowed.

### Fixing it

It seems logical that the fix we're looking for is to ensure that `Self: Sized` when we want to do a coercion. The obvious way to do this would be to make `Self` *always* `Sized`, that is, override the default `?Sized` bound as follows:

```
trait Array: Sized {
  fn as_foo(&self) {
    let _ = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
  }
}

fn main() {}
```

Looks good!

Except there's the small point that it doesn't work; but at least it's for a difference reason, we're making progress! Trait objects can only be made out of traits that are "object safe" (i.e. safe to be made into a trait object), and having `Sized` `Self` is one of the things that breaks object safety:

```
<anon>:3:13: 3:17 error: cannot convert to a trait object because trait `Array` is not object-safe [E0038]
<anon>:3     let _ = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
                     ^~~~
<anon>:3:13: 3:17 note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
<anon>:3     let _ = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
                     ^~~~
<anon>:3:13: 3:17 note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
<anon>:3     let _ = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
                     ^~~~
```

(I filed the double printing of the note as [#20692](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20692).)

Back to the drawing board. There's a few other "easy" possibilities for a solution:

- define an extension trait `trait ArrayExt: Sized + Array { fn as_foo(&self) { ... } }` and implement it for all `Sized + Array` types
- just use a free function `fn array_as_foo<A: Array>(x: &A) { ... }`

However, these don't necessarily work for every use case, e.g. specific types can't customise the behaviour by overloading the default method. However, fortunately there is a fix!

#### The Turon Trick

(Named for Aaron Turon, who discovered it.)

Using generalised `where` clauses we can be highly specific about when `Self` should implement `Sized`, restricting it to just the method(s) where it is required, without infecting the rest of the trait:

```
trait Array {
  fn as_foo(&self) where Self: Sized {
    let _ = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
  }
}

fn main() {}
```

This compiles just fine! By using the `where` clause like this, the compiler understands that (a) the coercion is legal because `Self` is `Sized` so `self` is a thin pointer, and (b) that the method is illegal to call on a trait object anyway, and so doesn't break object safety. To see it being disallowed, changing the body of `as_foo` to

```
let x = self as &Array; // coerce to a trait object
x.as_foo();
```

gives

```
<anon>:4:7: 4:15 error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Array`
<anon>:4     x.as_foo();
               ^~~~~~~~
```

as expected.

### Wrapping it all up

Making this change to the original unsimplified code is as simple adding that `where` clause to the `as_foo` method:

```
struct Foo<'a, T> { //'
  parent:&'a (Array<T> + 'a)
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> {
  pub fn new(parent:&Array<T>) -> Foo<T> {
    return Foo {
      parent: parent
    };
  }
}

trait Array<T> {
  fn as_foo(&self) -> Foo<T> where Self: Sized {
    return Foo::new(self);
  }
}

fn main() {
}
```

which compiles without error. (NB. I had to remove the unnecessary `<T>` in `pub fn new<T>` because that was causing inference failures.)

(I have some in-progress blog posts that go into trait objects, object safety and the Turon trick, they will appear on [/r/rust](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust) in the near future: [first one](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/peeking-inside-trait-objects/).)